# Add condition for the last Image in an ImageCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, imagecollection

I'm building a function that compute the difference between values in 2 images in an image collection. Here is the function I wrote :

```
function DailyDifference(img){
  var date_0 = ee.Date(img.get("date"))
  var date_1 = date_0.advance(1, "day")
  var second = ee.Image(Modis_chloa.filter(ee.Filter.equals("date", date_1)).first())
  var difference = img.subtract(second)
  return img.set('difference', difference)
}
```

But I got a problem with the last image of my ImageCollection because there is no date after the last day, I need to add a condition to handle this error. I also need a condition for the some date with a time step of 2 days between them. Indeed this problem causes the following error :
Here is the error I got when mapping my function on a ImageCollection : Error in map(ID=A2013307):
Image.subtract: Parameter 'image2' is required

Here is a link to my full code if you want to reproduce the error : https://code.earthengine.google.com/0f0b2b5487f53d97745138943ca9f23d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `ee.Algorithms.If()`, but it's something you typically try to [avoid](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#avoid_eealgorithmsif). A more efficient option is to use a join:

```
var Modis_diff = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.Join.saveBest({matchKey: 'second', measureKey: 'timeDiff'})
    .apply({
      primary: Modis_chloa, 
      secondary: Modis_chloa,
      condition: ee.Filter.and(
        ee.Filter.maxDifference({
          difference: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2, // Max 2 days difference
          leftField: 'system:time_start',
          rightField: 'system:time_start'
        }),
        ee.Filter.greaterThan({
          leftField: 'system:time_start', 
          rightField: 'system:time_start'
        })
      )
    })
    .map(function (image) {
      image = ee.Image(image)
      var second = ee.Image(image.get('second'))
      return image.subtract(second)
    })
)
```

The downside with this whole approach is that it only works on pairs of images. If either the current image or `second` have a pixel masked, the diff will be masked. If that is the behavior you want, no problem. If you instead need the diff between adjacent non-masked observations, you have some more work to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot it does exactly what I wanted !

Comment: I also want to add a condition to select images with a minimum difference of 1 day but I did not find the minDifference function. Do you now if there is another way to do it ?

Comment: The `greaterThan()` filter ensures you don't get the same image. I don't think you can have a min difference directly in the join condition. You could use a `saveAll()` join and filter out the images with too short distance. In this case, wouldn't `greaterThan()` suffice?

Comment: My goal is to make the difference between 2 images with a difference of 2 days and to exclude the image with a difference of 1 day. I don't know if my explication is very clear, do you see what i want to do ?

Comment: I tried to use the ````greaterThan()```` function with ````'system:time_start' + 1000*60*60*24*1```` (for a one day difference) but I does not work

Comment: In this case, I'd use a `saveAll()` join. That will give you a list of images, all within 2 days, assuming you keep the condition the same. When mapping over the collection, you could then pick the correct image from the list - the one 2 days after.

Comment: I've got an issue to substract for the image without 2 days images. I tried to map this function : ````.map(function(image) {
      var image = ee.Image(image)
      var date_plus1 = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).advance(1, 'day')
      var second = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(image.get('diff'))
      var more = ee.Image(second.filter(ee.Filter.gt('date', date_plus1)).first())
      return image.subtract(more)
      .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"])
    }````

Comment: I would suggest that you make a separate question for this issue. It's not possible to provide a clear answer in the space available here.

Comment: Yes I've done it thanks